# Select from SQL into an array

Tags: php, mysql, json

I tried to find some related answer but didn't find anything to work.

I want to select * from an table ( currently there are 5 rows in that table ) and the results stored in an array.

This is my function.

```
public function listAllRides() {

        $index = 0;
        $row = array();
        $data = array();
        $result = array();

        $resu = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM rides ");

           $resu->execute();
           $ride = $resu->get_result()->fetch_assoc();

            // this echo is to check if the query works. But only the first row 
                // is printed here  
           echo json_encode($ride)."<br>";


            if ($resu->execute()) {

                while ($row = $resu->fetch()) {
                $data[$index]['id'] = $row;
                $data[$index]['unique_id'] = $row;
                $data[$index]['destinatie'] = $row;

                 // also tried this :
                //$data[$index]['id'] = $row['id'];
                //$data[$index]['unique_id'] = $row['unique_id'];
                //$data[$index]['destinatie'] = $row['destinatie'];

                $index++;

                echo json_encode($data)."<br>";

                    }
                    echo json_encode($data)."<br>";
                    $resu->close();

                }
                else {
                            return false;
                         }



        }
```

The results that I am getting :

```
{"id":34,"unique_id":"59f8afdc2bf201.64404165","destinatie":"dera","driver":"123","kmride":"112233","created_at":"2017-10-31 19:16:12","updated_at":null}

[{"id":true,"unique_id":true,"destinatie":true}]

[{"id":true,"unique_id":true,"destinatie":true},"id":true,"unique_id":true,"destinatie":true}]

[{"id":true,"unique_id":true,"destinatie":true},"id":true,"unique_id":true,"destinatie":true},{"id":true,"unique_id":true,"destinatie":true}]

[{"id":true,"unique_id":true,"destinatie":true},"id":true,"unique_id":true,"destinatie":true},"id":true,"unique_id":true,"destinatie":true},"id":true,"unique_id":true,"destinatie":true}]

[{"id":true,"unique_id":true,"destinatie":true},"id":true,"unique_id":true,"destinatie":true},"id":true,"unique_id":true,"destinatie":true},"id":true,"unique_id":true,"destinatie":true},{"id":true,"unique_id":true,"destinatie":true}]
```

MODIFIED CODE :

```
public function listAllRides() {

        $index = 0;
        $row = array();
        $data = array();
        $result = array();

        $resu = $this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM rides ");

        $ride = $resu->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $ride;
}

It works, like this .. thanks for the answer Ramsés Fernández

What if I need to narrow the select : 

public function getRideByDestination($destinatie) {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM rides WHERE destinatie = ?");
         $stmt->bind_param("s", $destinatie);

         if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $ride = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();

              return $ride;
            }
         else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

It returns just one row. The first row of the query.

Comment: You're getting back the JSON you asked for. What do you want it to look like?

Comment: You're doing `json_encode`, which converts an array to a string. If you want to keep it an array but still show the results, try `print_r( $data )` or `var_dump( $data )` instead of `echo json_encode( $data )`.

Comment: If you do want the json though, you've already got it. These are all valid JSON syntaxes. The only difference between `[]` and `{}` is that `[]` is an array (numerical keys), and `{}` is an object (named keys).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need a prepare statement you can use this code for get all result set.

```
   $resu = $this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM rides ");
   $ride = $resu->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

$ride now is an array associative with all records from rides

You are breaking the execution flow of the function in the if the else it is not necessary.

```
if ($stmt->execute()) {
$result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
       $array[]=$row;
    }
  $stmt->close();
  return array;
}
return false;
```

Comment: I know but he need saved a result on ```array $ride = $resu->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);```  save a result on array assoc, He dont need to do a prepare statements and dont need do a fetch assoc for save result when the method ```fetch_all``` exist

Comment: mysqli have [fetch](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) and [get_result()](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

Comment: No problem xDDD

Comment: I dont understand you

Comment: Like this I get, indeed, the results into an array. I used prepare because I also need a function for query : (SELECT * FROM rides WHERE destinatie = ?) ; $stmt->bind_param("s", $destinatie); In this case the MYSQLI_ASOC is not working.

Comment: Yes you have a reason but for this `$this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM rides ");` you can use

Comment: And if I want to SELECT * FROM rides WHERE destinatie = ? I am trying to do that for some time now. Shall I submit another question or can You answer here ?

Comment: And yes, you are right .. for "SELECT * FROM rides "  it works.

Comment: try a while for fetch_assoc

Comment: you can try with bind_result

Comment: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement ... referring to the  $stmt->bind_result($ride); line.

Comment: try add all parameters that you get on select

Comment: and try again the last code without bind result and store_result

Comment: Solved problem??

Comment: The idea is to parse the result from the query and insert the values into another array that can be returned from this function.

Comment: Illegal offset type in tions.php on line 90 .. the $array[$row] = $r; line

Comment: the last I modified

Comment: Yes .. my mistake. Now it returns ok. Thank you. the $result->fetch_assoc() did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ramsés Fernández,
Final working code:

public function getRideByDestination($destinatie) {

```
    $index = 0;
    $data = array();
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM rides WHERE destinatie = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $destinatie);

         if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $data[] = $row;

            }
    }
        $stmt->close();

        return $data;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Probably you can do the assigment like `$data[$index] = array_map('id', $row['id'])`